# flaw in logic to display sum of array

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop, definition

Q) Take input in 1D-Array from user, create new array for the sum of it's values , for e.g if array that is passed is : | 1 | | 2 | | 3 | then it should print |1| | 3| |6| , it will plus the content of array i.e 1+2 = 3, 1+2+3 = 6, it should not change the array[0] value.i tried to make the program but it have flaws

```
#include <stdio.h>
void subtotal (float[], int);
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter the size of array"); // taking size of array from user
    scanf("%d",&n);
    float a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) // loop for entering elements of array
    {
        printf("Enter the element of array");
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);
    }
    subtotal(a,n); // function call
}
void subtotal (float a[],int n)  // function definition
{
    int i,j;
    float c;
    float sum=0,minus=0;
    c = a[0];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)  // nested loop to calculate sum of array element
    {
        sum = sum - minus;
        for (j=0;j<=i;j++) // this loop is used to store sum value
        { 

        sum = sum+a[i];
        minus = sum;
      }
    a[i] = sum; // new array element a[i] will be sum;  
     sum = 0; 
    if (i==0) // if i==0 that means we don't need to change the first value of array;
    {
        a[i] = c; // a[0] was stored in extra variable 'c' , hence a[i] = c;
    }
}
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) // this loop to print the updated array
    {
        printf("%.2f \t",a[i]);
    }
}
```

tell me the changes i can make to fix the flaws.

Comment: "it have flaws" what flaws exactly?

Comment: This is an excellend example of the question "How can I learn to use a debugger"?

Comment: You don't need a nested loop, you just need a variable to hold the running total as you loop through the array once. Also, you are not creating a new array as instructed, you are just overwriting the original array.

Comment: @IanAbbott can you provide code of what you said ? i am unable to understand what logic to use if it's not nested loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating all but the first element of an array with the rolling sum is much simpler than you think. The following version of `subtotal()` will do want you want:

```c
void subtotal(float a[], int n)  // function definition
{
    int i;
    float sum = a[0]; // Initialize our sum to the FIRSTelement
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) { // Now, for all OTHER elements ...
        sum += a[i]; // ... add the original value of a[i] to the running sum ...
        a[i] = sum;  // ... and THEN replace that element with the running sum.
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // this loop to print the updated array
    {
        printf("%.2f \t", a[i]);
    }
}
```

*(I would add that I agree with Vlad's suggestion that the output part of the function is better placed in the body of `main`.)*

Please feel fre to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: thanks man, because in question it's not necessary for the function to return array, it's easy for me to just print out the new array in function,

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should do one thing: update the array according to the requirement.

It is the function main where the updated array should be outputted.

Your function implementation is unclear and too complicated.

For example in the comment to this if statement

```
if (i==0) // if i==0 that means we don't need to change the first value of array;
{
    a[i] = c; // a[0] was stored in extra variable 'c' , hence a[i] = c;
}
```

there is written that

> // if i==0 that means we don't need to change the first value of
>   array;

and at the same time the value of  `a[0]` is updated.

The same is done in the statement above this if statement

```
a[i] = sum; // new array element a[i] will be sum;
```

The function can be defined much simpler the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void subtotal( float a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a[i] += a[i-1];
    }
}    

int main(void) 
{
    float a[] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    subtotal( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.1f ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1.0 3.0 6.0
```

If you need to place the partial sums in another array then the function can be defined the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void subtotal( float a[], size_t n, float b[] )
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        b[0] = a[0];

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            b[i] = a[i] + b[i-1];
        }
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    float a[] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    float b[sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )];
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    subtotal( a, N, b );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.1f ", b[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
1.0 3.0 6.0
```

Comment: because of this line "c = a[0];" i stored a[0] in c. that's why if i == 0, then a[i] = c; which was already a[0] .

Comment: @Incognito In any case the first element of the array is updated. So these tricks do not make sense.

Comment: well, you are using many things which we aren't taught yet, for instance pointer, and these lines "float b[sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )];
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );"

Comment: @Incognito Just substitute the expression sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) for the size of the array for example const size_t N = 3; In your program that prompts the user to enter the size of the array you will use just the variable n. What is important is the function definition. There is only one very simple and clear loop.